# Synchronization with C++ atomic memory fence

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I have a question about the synchronization of the code below using memory fence.

```
std::atomic<int> a = 0;
std::atomic<int> b = 0;

void increase_b() {
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
  b.store(1, std::memory_ordered_relaxed);
}

bool diff() {
  int val_a = a.load(std::memory_ordered_relaxed);
  int val_b = b.load(std::memory_ordered_relaxed);
  return val_b > val_a;
}

void f1() {
  increase_b();
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}

void f2() {
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
  bool result = diff();
}

int main() {
  std::thread t1(f1);
  std::thread t2(f2);
  t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

Assume t1 has finished `f1` and then t2 just started `f2`, will t2 
see `b` incremented?

Comment: I don't think you can refer to absolute time, as in "has finished". You need to see the two threads not sharing a common time reference. The guarantees you have is that all reads and writes will appear consistent. Nothing about *when*. But hey, I'm not confident, so looking forward to solid answers.

Comment: For this simple case, you don't need `atomic_thread_fence` here, since you can't tell when `f1` will run compared to `f2`. So the only integrity you can ensure is that the compiler will not see an intermediate value when it's incrementing `b` or accessing it (and it'll not reorder the code).

Comment: I understand there is a race between t1 and t2. But what I wanted to know is will t2 see `b` changed assuming t1 executes `f1` before t2 executes `f2`?

Comment: No. Memory Order guarantees the order side effects become visible, not when or whether they become visible.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin, you mean even with `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)`, t2 might not see `b == 1` when t2 starts `f2` after t1 finishes?

Comment: `Assume t1 has finished f1 and then t2 just started f2` this is very synthetic condition as it isn't verified deterministically in your code, but in case of hypothetical situation when the execution accidentally happens to meet this condition, the last issued fence guarantees visibility `b` store operation to another thread. But again in the given code it may happen rather accidentally than intentionally.

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is overcomplicated.  `a=0` never changes so it *always* reads as 0.  You might as well just have `atomic<int> b=0;` and only a single load that just return `b.load`.

> Assume t1 has finished f1 and then t2 just started f2, will t2 see b incremented?

There's no way for you to detect that this is how the timing worked out, unless you put `t1.join()` *ahead* of `std::thread t2(f2);` construction.  That would require that everything in thread 2 is sequenced after everything in thread 1.  (I think even without a `seq_cst` fence at the end of f1, but that doesn't hurt.  I think thread.join makes sure everything done inside a thread is visible after `thread.join`)

But yes, that ordering can happen by chance, and then of course it works.

There's no guarantee that's even a meaningful condition in C++ terms.

But sure for most (all?) real implementations it's something that can happen.  And a `thread_fence(mo_seq_cst)` will compile to a full barrier that blocks that thread until the store commits (becomes globally visible to all threads).  So execution can't leave f1 until reads from other threads can see the updated value of `b`.  (The C++ standard defines ordering and fences in terms of creating synchronizes-with relationships, not in terms of compiling to full barriers that flush the store buffer.  The standard doesn't mention a store buffer or StoreLoad reordering or any of the CPU memory-order things.)

Given the synthetic condition, the threads actually are ordered wrt. each other, and it works just like if everything had been done in a single thread.

---

The loads in `diff()` aren't ordered wrt. each other because they're both `mo_relaxed`.  But `a` is never modified by any thread so the only question is whether `b.load()` can happen before the thread even started, before the `f1` store is visible.  In real implementations it can't because of what "*and then* t2 just started f2" means.  **If it could load the old value, then you wouldn't be able to say "*and then*", so it's almost a tautology.**

The `thread_fence(seq_cst)` before the loads doesn't really help anything.  I guess it stops `b.load()` from reordering with the thread-startup machinery.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!